# How to add event on dynamically created table element inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML code like this

```
 <table id="Table1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">
                    Srno.
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Emp code
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Name
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Mobile No
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Delete
                </th>
            </tr>               
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have a button and when the `button` is clicked the the new `tr` with 4 `td` added into table, the code become like this.

```
 <table id="Table1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">
                    Srno.
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Emp code
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Name
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Mobile No
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Delete
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    1
                </td>
                <td style="display: none;">
                    198
                </td>
                <td>
                    SHR003
                </td>
                <td>
                    Saurabh khandelwal
                </td>
                <td>
                    9891491920
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img class="clsImage" src="../../images/delete1.png" style="cursor: pointer;">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Now i used `delete` image to delete current row which is `dynamically` added in `iframe`.For same am using that `Jquery` code :

```
$("iframe").contents().find('body').on("click", '.clsImage', function (e) {
    alert('111');
       });
```

But after click on `delete` image button the newest added `tr` inside the iframe is not gives `alert`.

I am using `Jquery 1.9.1'

Please help me

Comment: The table is inside the iframe? Or only the clsImage?

Comment: Hi the table is inside the `iframe` and `clsImage` is just added to get element by `classname`.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is that you are trying to bind the `click` event to elements inside the `iframe` before it has finished to load. You can try to bind the event handler after the iframe has loaded:

```
    $('iframe').load(function () {
      $(this).contents().find('body').on('click', '.clsImage', function () {
        alert('111');
      });
    });
```

EDIT: This is a simple example of what I mean. You need to *give* enough time to the `iframe` to build its own DOM before you can register any handler.

This is the content of **index.html**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('iframe').load(function () {
          $(this).contents().find('body').on('click', '.clsImage', function () {
            alert('111');
          });
        });
        $('button').click(function () {
          var $table = $('iframe').contents().find('table');
          $table.append('<tr><td>1</td><td style="display: none">198</td><td>SHR003</td><td>Saurabh khandelwal</td><td>9891491920</td><td><img class="clsImage" src="../../images/delete1.png" style="cursor: pointer;"></td></tr>');
        });
      });
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>add</button>
    <iframe src="table.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the content of **table.html**:

```
<table id="Table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">
        Srno.
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        Emp code
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        Name
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        Mobile No
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        Delete
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey the row is added in the table is inside the `iframe` and its happen only when `iframe` is fully loaded.

Comment: When do you register the click handler?. Is it registered in the `jQuery.ready` callback? When the row is added doesn't really matter, because you are registering a delegated event on the iframe body for all the clicks in a `.clsImage`.

Comment: Exactly. Then what I think it's happening is that when you try to register the click handler nothing guarantees you that the iframe document is ready. I mean, when the `$(document).ready` executes the iframe may not be loaded yet and you are just trying to register the click handler on an empty DOM.